# Const variables in c++

Tags: c++, constants

AFAIK  we cannot change a value of a constant variable in C.
But i faced this interview question as below:

In C++, we have procedure to change the value of a constant variable.
Could anybody tell me how could we do it?

Comment: i really wish interviewers would concentrate on more important things like whether the person has a passion for programming, curiosity for new things and has a certain amount of EQ as well.

Comment: Knowing about const_cast is a perfectly valid question in a series designed to test someones c++ knowledge. Problem arises when you *only* test for language knowledge.

Comment: @Erik so the interviewee is nervous and forgets about this particular thing in the interview and as such doesn't get the job, fair? More interesting is best practices in C++.

Comment: @Anders: Depends on the position. When we advertise for experienced senior c++ programmers, they better remember const_cast. A junior out of school, no, but they should answer *some* of the language-knowledge questions when we indicate in the ad that we want people with c++ knowledge

Comment: @Erik: At the same time, I use `const_cast<>` so rarely (I have used it only once) that I would have to look up the C++ standard every time I use it to make sure it doesn't invoke undefined behavior, despite the fact that I know very well what it does. And when I do use it, it's buried deep in library code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the circumstances, I think I'd have explained the situation: attempting to change the value of a *variable* that's const gives undefined behavior. What he's probably asking about is how to change a variable that isn't itself const, but to which you've received a pointer or reference to const. In this case, when you're *sure* the variable itself is *not* const-qualified, you can cast away the const-ness with `const_cast`, and proceed to modify.

If you do the same when the variable itself is const-qualified the compiler will allow the code to compile, but the result will be undefined behavior. The attempt at modifying the variable might succeed -- or it might throw an exception, abort the program, re-format your NAS appliance's hard drives, or pretty much anything else.

It's probably also worth mentioning that when/if a variable is likely to need to be used this way, you can specify that the variable itself is mutable. This basically means that the variable in question is *never* const qualified, even if the object of which it's a part *is* const qualified.

Answer (score 8):

You can modify mutable data members of a const-qualified class-type object:

```
struct awesome_struct {
    awesome_struct() : x(0) { }
    mutable int x;
};

int main() {
    const awesome_struct a;
    a.x = 42;
}
```

The behavior here is well-defined.

Comment: I had this in mind when writing my own post, but didn't know how to put it without using const member function. Good Job. +1!

Answer (score 6):

There is no perfect way to cast away const-ness of a variable(which is `const` by definition) without invoking UB

Most probably the interviewers have no idea what they are talking about. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the value of a constant variable. Trying to do so *by cheating the compiler*, invokes undefined behavior. The compiler may not be smart enough to tell you what you're doing is illegal, though!

Or maybe, you mean this:

```
const char *ptr= "Nawaz";
ptr = "Sarfaraz";
```

??

If so, then it's changing the value of the pointer itself, which is **not** constant, rather the data `ptr` points to is constant, and you cannot change that for example by writing `ptr[2]='W';`.

Answer (score 0):

The interviewer was looking for `const_cast`. As an added bonus, you can explain scenarios where `const_cast` make sense, such as `const_cast<MyClass *>(this)->doSomething()` (which can be perfectly valid, although IMO not very clean), and scenarios where it can be dangerous , such as casting away constness of a passed const reference and therefore breaking the contract your functions signature provides.

Answer (score 0):

If a const variable requires a change in value, then you have discovered a flaw in the design (under most, if not all, situations).  If the design is yours, great! - you have an opportunity to improve your code.

If the design is not yours, good luck because the UB comment above is spot-on.  In embedded systems, const variables may be placed in ROM. Performing tricks in an attempt to make such a variable writable lead to some spectacular failures.  Furthermore, the problem extends beyond simple member variables.  Methods and/or functions that are marked const may be optimized in such away that "lack of const-ness" becomes nonsensical.

(Take this "comment-as-answer" as a statement on the poor interview question.)